# How to combine \textbf and \textsf with \newcommand?

Tags: fonts, macros

I am trying to define a command as a shortcut for this code:

```
 \textsf{\textbf{special bold type}}
```

I haven't been able to apply related answers to my problem. Either the code doesn't compute, or it gives out something I don't want. For instance:

```
\documentclass{article}  
\newcommand{\val}[1]{{\textsf{\textbf}}}  

\begin{document}  

normal text  
\textsf{\textbf{this is working}}  
\val{this doesn't appear at all}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You've got `\val` taking one argument but never use it! Perhaps you meant `\newcommand{\val}[1]{\textsf{\textbf{#1}}}` or alternatively `\newcommand{\val}{\textsf{\textbf}}` would work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot `#1` in your `\newcommand`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\val}[1]{{\sffamily\bfseries#1}}
\newcommand{\valalternative}[1]{\textbf{\textsf{#1}}}% as an alternative
\begin{document}
\noindent normal text\\
\textsf{\textbf{this is working}}\\
\val{this doesn't appear at all}
\end{document}
```

Works alright I think.
[image]

Comment: Yes, thank you! I didn't know there to put the #1. Much obliged!